# FakeItEasy Returning Func with origin arguments in C#

Tags: c#, fakeiteasy

I try to run some tests with FakeItEasy and my purpose is to replace one method by another for a different return value. The tricky thing for me is to redirect the origin call argument to the replace method. Invokes works fine but dont change the result. (may i do something wrong)

Here is what i come up with

```
Func<string, string> func = delegate (string request)
{
   return $"Replaced {request}";
};
var service = A.Fake<MyService>();

A.CallTo(() => service.DoAction(A<string>._)).Returns<string>(func(A<string>._));
// func(A<string>._) cause an exception, i need to have arg from DoAction here

// following line works fine but dont change return
A.CallTo(() => service.DoAction(A<string>._)).Invokes((string request) => func(request));

// result is empty here but should have "Replaced Test"
var result = service.DoAction("Test");
```

Can someone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for

```
A.CallTo(() => service.DoAction(A<string>._)) 
    .ReturnsLazily((string request) => func(request));
```

You can see more more on this in the [Return Values Calculated at Call Time](https://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/specifying-return-values/#return-values-calculated-at-call-time) topic of the documentation.